# Running IPython in 32 bit (OS X)

Tags: python, macos, ipython, 32bit-64bit

I am trying to run IPython in 32bit (and ultimately IPython Notebook). I have installed the universal build of Python 2.7.6.1. To launch IPython in 32bit I'm running `arch -i386 ipython`, but receive the following error:

```
ERROR:root:code for hash md5 was not found.
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/python/2.7.6_1/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/hashlib.py", line 139, in <module>
    globals()[__func_name] = __get_hash(__func_name)
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/python/2.7.6_1/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/hashlib.py", line 91, in __get_builtin_constructor
    raise ValueError('unsupported hash type ' + name)
ValueError: unsupported hash type md5
ERROR:root:code for hash sha1 was not found.
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/python/2.7.6_1/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/hashlib.py", line 139, in <module>
    globals()[__func_name] = __get_hash(__func_name)
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/python/2.7.6_1/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/hashlib.py", line 91, in __get_builtin_constructor
    raise ValueError('unsupported hash type ' + name)
ValueError: unsupported hash type sha1
ERROR:root:code for hash sha224 was not found.
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/python/2.7.6_1/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/hashlib.py", line 139, in <module>
    globals()[__func_name] = __get_hash(__func_name)
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/python/2.7.6_1/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/hashlib.py", line 91, in __get_builtin_constructor
    raise ValueError('unsupported hash type ' + name)
ValueError: unsupported hash type sha224
ERROR:root:code for hash sha256 was not found.
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/python/2.7.6_1/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/hashlib.py", line 139, in <module>
    globals()[__func_name] = __get_hash(__func_name)
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/python/2.7.6_1/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/hashlib.py", line 91, in __get_builtin_constructor
    raise ValueError('unsupported hash type ' + name)
ValueError: unsupported hash type sha256
ERROR:root:code for hash sha384 was not found.
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/python/2.7.6_1/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/hashlib.py", line 139, in <module>
    globals()[__func_name] = __get_hash(__func_name)
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/python/2.7.6_1/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/hashlib.py", line 91, in __get_builtin_constructor
    raise ValueError('unsupported hash type ' + name)
ValueError: unsupported hash type sha384
ERROR:root:code for hash sha512 was not found.
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/python/2.7.6_1/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/hashlib.py", line 139, in <module>
    globals()[__func_name] = __get_hash(__func_name)
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/python/2.7.6_1/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/hashlib.py", line 91, in __get_builtin_constructor
    raise ValueError('unsupported hash type ' + name)
ValueError: unsupported hash type sha512
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/bin/ipython", line 9, in <module>
    load_entry_point('ipython==2.3.0', 'console_scripts', 'ipython')()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pkg_resources.py", line 339, in load_entry_point
    return get_distribution(dist).load_entry_point(group, name)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pkg_resources.py", line 2457, in load_entry_point
    return ep.load()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pkg_resources.py", line 2171, in load
    ['__name__'])
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/IPython/__init__.py", line 45, in <module>
    from .config.loader import Config
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/IPython/config/__init__.py", line 16, in <module>
    from .application import *
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/IPython/config/application.py", line 32, in <module>
    from IPython.config.configurable import SingletonConfigurable
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/IPython/config/configurable.py", line 32, in <module>
    from .loader import Config, LazyConfigValue
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/IPython/config/loader.py", line 34, in <module>
    from IPython.utils.path import filefind, get_ipython_dir
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/IPython/utils/path.py", line 24, in <module>
    from hashlib import md5
ImportError: cannot import name md5
```

Btw. I receive no error when running `arch -i386 python`.

Many thanks!

Comment: And it works in 64-bit?

Comment: @Droppy: Yes it does.

Comment: can you do `from hashlib import md5` normally (probably not)? apparently that comes from the openssl library, which maybe the 'universal' install doesn't include a 32 bit version of openssl to implement it?

Comment: Corley, you're right, it doesn't work in 32bit. I think the openssl installed by brew is not universal. Do you know how to fix it?

Comment: Use Macports where such problems don't occur, as far as I am aware.